# Can't retrieve the session on clicking of browser's back button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have rails application that calculates prices of goods and I set prices in session. I have 'back' button in my application. When I clicks on 'back' link, I will get my previous session values like 'prices','goods' I purchased.
But when I clicks on 'browsers' back button,I won't get my session values, I have to refresh the page for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have caching issues... The browser remembers what it saw before, and thinks it's the same (without even going to the trouble to ask the server any more). Try if [this article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm) helps

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to prevent the browser from caching your pages so that they get refreshed when the user clicks the Back button. This [article](http://lab.artlung.com/anti-cache/) should help.